# Implementing Configurable Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, .net

**Existing Implementation:**

I have implemented factory pattern for DB connection. I am having three DB like sql,oracle and sybase.  All three classes like sqlConnector,OracleConnector and SybaseConnector has implemented in Iconnect interface and in the factory method i have created the object of these concrete classes(sqlConnector,OracleConnector and SybaseConnector) based on switch case and returned specific object.

**Scenario:**

I want to modify this factory pattern and want to remove all switch case from factory method and want to configure through config file/xml and also without using reflection and spring.net. Suppose tommorow i introduce new db type , i don't want to change the code.I will make entry in the config/xml ,it should returned the object to client without changing factory.

**Question:**

How i can implement configurable factory pattern  means suppose tomorrow introducing new db type like "MySql", i don't want to change the code of factory.

Comment: Do you use a dependency injection library?

Comment: This is exactly what dependency injection frameworks do. If you've picked Sprint.NET then just read the documentation and try to implement what you need. If you get stuck come back here with your code and ask a question.

Comment: @ Enigmativity ,Thanks, I have implemented using Spring.Net. But I don't want to implement it using spring.net

Comment: True, some dependency injection frameworks will allow configuration via config/XML. Of course you could always roll you own, though I don't advise that. If memory serves, Unity (https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) supports that. But "configurable factory pattern" can go beyond the normally expected use case of DI, which is why I answered (below) the way I did. (Yes, you could force a DI container to do this. I just wouldn't agree it's the best general approach.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question, but I think that the technology that will best serve you is [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx), or MEF.

MEF is an integral part of .NET that allows you to include additional components into your solution *without having to know what those components are beforehand*. MEF automatically discovers and includes components into your solution *after* your solution is built.

You define the points where your solution can be extended; each component is written to take advantage of those extensibility points; MEF ties them together automatically.

If you have used an Inversion of Control framework, like a Dependency Injection library (Ninject, Castle Windsor, SimpleInjector, etc.), then you have already done something a little like this, and the concepts should be somewhat familiar to you.

Explaining it and showing you how to use it will take a book. However, I'm reasonably certain that it will solve your problem best. There are books, blogs, videos, and many, many examples.